# Vector layer parameter in QGIS script takes wrong layer

Tags: pyqgis, parameters, vector-layer, postgis-2.3

I have 6 postgis layers in my QGIS project and all of them have the same data source but different joined data.

When accessing these layers from a python script with a vector layer parameter (like this `##layer=vector`) it will always take the same layer (the first one in alphabetical order), no matter which one I select in the drop down selector.

```
   ##layer=vector
   import processing
   lyrName = processing.getObject(layer) 
   progress.setInfo(lyrName.name())
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any idea?

Comment: The documentation says that vector parameters return _strings containing the filepath of the corresponding object_ (read it [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html)), which for what I've tested is what you see under **Layer source** in the **General** tab of the layer **Properties** window.
The problem is that all my layers share that filepath (as the only difference between them is the joined table) so maybe vector parameters should also return the layer name to avoid this kind of situations.

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is setting a query filter on each layer which will not affect the features shown. That would be something like this: `"any_field" NOT IN ('value_not_present_in_field')`. And evidently that value will be different for each layer (for example `"any_field" NOT IN ('a')` for the first layer, `"any_field" NOT IN ('b')` for the second and so on).